# CSS en Apache: No admite archivos internos

Tags: javascript, css, apache

Tengo *Apache 2.2*, en *Centos*, y tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un archivo muy simple en *HTML*. Cuando llamo una librería (*CSS/Javascript*) de un archivo externo, funciona sin problemas, por ejemplo *jQuery*, **pero si el archivo se encuentra dentro del mismo equipo, entonces mis navegadores no la reconocen, bien sea Chrome, Opera, etc.**

De hecho el llamado a los archivos (ejemplo un *CSS*) se hace sobre la misma ruta donde está el archivo *HTML*, que publico a continuación:

**probando.html:**

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> 
    <title>Hello</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Hello</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**styles.css:**

```
h1 {color:blue;font-size:70px;text-align:center;color:gray;}
```

He revisado usuarios y permisos, todo en orden.

Comment: Todo lo que esté dentro de la ruta que pongas en el DocumentRoot del apache lo vas a poder ver/invocar, lo que esté fuera no. Posiblemente lo que ocurra es que los archivos que intentas invocar estén fuera del DocumentRoot.

Comment: Por un ejemplo en tu pregunta, mostrando cómo relacionas los recursos locales y cómo los estás poniendo en la estructura de archivos

Comment: Saludos,

De hecho el llamado a los archivos (ejemplo un CSS) se hace sobre la misma ruta donde está el archivo HTML, que publico a continuación:

Mis archivos son:

probando.html:

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

 <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>

styles.css:

h1 {color:blue;font-size:70px;text-align:center;color:gray;}

Comment: En la pregunta. Edítala, que allí puedes darle formato y añadir todo lo que necesites

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo pregunta editada

Comment: Súper! Gracias. Cuando cargas el html, puedes mirar las opciones de desarrollador y ver qué sale en la pestaña network cuando intenta cargar el recurso?

Comment: @Alfabravo utilizando Chrome me aparece:
probando.html:8 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: Verifica que los archivos existan o estén en la misma carpeta que el HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la estructura de tu HTML, de acuerdo al siguiente ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Mi documento HTML</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/mi-estilo.css"/>
<script src="assets/js/mi-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>HTML</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Particularmente te recomiendo que leas acerca de HTML. https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/xhtml

También podrías intentar la permisividad de archivos .css y .js, aunque para ello deberías de tener habilitado el MOD REWRITE en tu APACHE. [EJEMPLO](https://www.neoguias.com/habilitar-el-modulo-rewrite-en-wamp-y-xampp/)

En ese mismo nivel, crea un archivo llamado .htaccess con el siguiente contenido:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho indagar, encontré una respuesta que me funcionó.  Ojalá sea de utilidad para quien la necesite.

En el archivo .htaccess agregué las siguientes líneas:

```html
<Files *.js>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    Header set Content-Type "application/javascript"
</Files>
<Files *.css>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    Header set Content-Type "text/css"
</Files>
```

Y una vez reiniciado el Apache, ya todo en orden.